# Create a custom exception and handle it with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have 2 projects both in .NET Core a "Business" project and a WebApi.

I'd like create a custom exception to throw from my "Business" project and try/catch in the controller and then do different action depending the exception type.

I try the classic way to create a custom exception (part of the code)

```
protected NegativeNumberException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  : base(info, context)
{
}
```

but `SerializationInfo` does not exist in .NET Core.

How can I do this ?

Comment: so if the question about how to deal with `SerializationInfo` in .Net Core, then you need to edit your question title...

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters) nuget package.

In general, you may use [package search](https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=System.Runtime.Serialization) site when you are looking for the specific type.

Comment: Why with .NET Core it's not possible to add an assembly like .NET "classic" :)

Comment: @Kris-I not sure that could answer in 1-2 sentences, that's why suggest you starting from reading about what is the .NET Standard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library. That should give you the understanding of when and why .NET library could be used with .Net Core

Comment: I'm not sure the formatters package is enough for that. .NET Core (at least true for 1.0 and 1.1) has removed the constructor which accepts the `SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context` parameters. so while you can add it on your own exception you can't serialize the base class, which is ultimatively `Exception`, one of the reasoning pointed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/2715#issuecomment-174761980) _In particular, we don't want to add types that require core framework types, such as exceptions and collections, having to implement serialization logic._

Comment: `[Seriablizable]` attribute may be enough for the BinarySerializer though, which makes it come-back in .NET Core/Standard 2.0, but it would still contradict the statement above of keeping base types (such as `Exception`) agnostic of serialization

Comment: For anyone coming here and wondering about the state of affairs without reading through that entire thread mentioned earlier, .NET Core supports binary serialization with a subset of types, including Exception and several "important Exception-derived types", which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization#serializable-types). The reasoning for the changes can be found here: [Scale back Serializable for .NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19119#issue-225189643)